# How to rotate enemies on 2D radar and clip them to circle shape?

Tags: c++, mathematics

I've been working on implementing a 2D radar for a 3D game lately, it's working fine in a very basic version. This is what is looks like:

[image: radar]

It works by transforming the 3D coordinates of the enemies nearby to the local player space and then drawing those coordinates with the center-offset of the radar circle.

Transforming the enemy positions (and adding them to a vector):

```
if (LocalPlayer)
{
    Vec3    diff;
    double  distance;
    position.clear();

    for (auto i = commonInfected.begin(); i != commonInfected.end(); ++i)
    {
        diff = (*i)->GetPosition() - Global::camera->GetPosition(true);
        distance = diff.xz().Length();

        if (diff < 100)
        {
            position.push_back(diff);
        }
    }
}
```

Drawing the enemies:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < position.size(); ++i)
    {
        pos.x = position[i].x;
        pos.y = position[i].z;

        pos += {80, 80}; // center of the circle

        context->DrawText("x", pos.x, pos.y);
    }
```

However, the problem I have is that the plotted enemies do not rotate with the player and that plotted enemies can "go out" of the circle shape of the radar. How do I approach this kind of problem?

I have seen and carefully read through this question but couldn't understand it.
[Plotting entities on a radar](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49335/plotting-entities-on-a-radar)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is almost perfect duplicate. Maybe you can focus on something that exactly gives you the problem, e.g. how to rotate knowing the ship facing direction or something ..

Comment: If [the previous question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49335/plotting-entities-on-a-radar) wasn't clear enough, that's an indication that it needs edits or a better answer. That's what [bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) are for.